# Excel VBA Pivot Table Object Required Error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, pivot-table

I've been trying to create a pivot table using VBA and I've encountered a 424 Object required runtime error. I recorded creating one then substituded the hard coded names/cells with variables.  I've been trying to get this figured out but I'm not sure where on the create line my error is.
Here's my code:

```
RangeArea = "R1C1:R" & RowCounts & "C70"
DataSource = CurrSheet & "!" & RangeArea
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Pivot Table"
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        RangeSheet.Range(DataSource), Version:=8). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Pivot Table!R3C1", TableName:="CVPivotTable" _
        , DefaultVersion:=8
```

CurrSheet is a global variable that was set earlier.

RowCounts is the number of rows that was determined in the main subroutine.

DataSource becomes: 2023-04 Revenue RecognitionManu!R1C1:R4468C70

The SourceData, TableDestination and TableName are the only things I changed.

When running the macro, the new sheet "Pivot Table" is created and is active when the macro stops.

Thanks for any and all advice

I also tried it with the new sheet named "PivotTable" as I saw a post about the space in the name causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is assigning `SourceData = RangeSheet.Range(DataSource)`. Have you assigned a worksheet object named `RangeSheet`? It looks like your variable DataSource is all you need. Try this:

```
RangeArea = "R1C1:R" & RowCounts & "C70"
DataSource = CurrSheet & "!" & RangeArea
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets.Add.Name = "PivotTable"
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        DataSource, Version:=8). _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="PivotTable!R3C1", TableName:="CVPivotTable" _
        , DefaultVersion:=8
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin,   
I think I had too many changes.  I changed it to SourceData = Datasource and it works fine.  Sometimes fresh eyes really help.